# ASP Classic can I use Response.AppendToLog in global.asa Application_onStart

Tags: asp-classic

In ASP Classic can i use `Response.AppendToLog` in `global.asa Application_onStart` ?

I would try to Log error when application starts, but i always get this error:

> erreur '8002802b'
>
> /v1/common/CAppInit.asp, line 21

line 21:

> Response.AppendToLog "****INIT DB ERROR****"

Comment: Here is the source for this question:
https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_appendtolog.asp#:~:text=The%20AppendToLog%20method%20adds%20a,string%20to%20the%20log%20entry.

Comment: Now since it seems like that line appears Kosher .. I assume that its something else .. could be anything from not having the actual rights for the ISSUSER  or something like that.  I would look into what allows you to write files in the first place and work backwards.

Now there is the Write Method to write to files .. but thats something different but see here:
https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_write.asp

Comment: You can’t use the `Response` object in the `global.asa` because there is no context for a response. The `global.asa` file deals with `Application` and `Session` level context. Think about it when the application starts there doesn’t need to be a response because there is no request, it operates outside of that pipeline.

Comment: @easleyfixed please stop quoting w3schools as a "source".

Comment: Here is the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524861(v=vs.90)).

Comment: Do you got a citation where using a good explanation link isn't good enough?  Most original sources read very blandly, and posting the original source sort of is slanderous to the OP because it assumes they haven't tried that, which to be fair they might not of, but chances are they did and it didn't help, so a lil useful explanation from a source doesn't feel like a bad idea to those seriously needing guidance.

Comment: @easleyfixed What value does the w3fools link have over the official documentation link?

Comment: Most of the time, easier to understand examples, and usually brevity.  One page of exact info versus 4 pages of technical jargon generally.  I don't see harm in both existing as a resources.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t use the `Response` object in the `global.asa` file because there is no context for a response. The `global.asa` file deals with `Application` and `Session` level context.

If you think about it, when the application starts there doesn’t need to be a response because there is no initial request, it operates entirely outside of that pipeline.

The definition of the [`Response.AppendToLog()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524861(v=vs.90)) is as follows;

> The AppendToLog method adds a string to the end of the Web server log entry for the request.

This means that an **initial request** is required, which makes using it in the context of application startup impossible.

The usual solution is to implement a custom logging function that can be utilised inside the context of the `Application` or `Session` startup events.